# immutable js - create or update a list nested inside a map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have to modify a system for picking assets to allow the user to pick multiple assets.  Currently we add one asset ID to a production ID map like this:

```
.setIn(['newRequest', 'productionAssets', action.productionId], action.assetId)
```

how can I modify this so that we create a new list if its the first, or append if its not the first?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this is two rounds. There maybe a more succinct version, but this works

```
if (s.hasIn(['newRequest', 'productionAssets', action.productionId])) {
        return s
          .updateIn(['newRequest', 'productionAssets', action.productionId], (prodAssets) => prodAssets.push(action.assetId))            
      } else {
        return s
          .setIn(['newRequest', 'productionAssets', action.productionId], fromJS([action.assetId]))             
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a one-liner like this:

```
return s.updateIn(['newRequest', 'productionAssets', action.productionId], l => (l || List()).push(fromJS(action.assetId)));
```

This way, if the value in path `['newRequest', 'productionAssets', action.productionId]` is `undefined`, you can initialise it with `List()` and then `push()` the new item right in. If the list does already exist you'll just be appending a new item to it.